# In php what does the 'double greater than' symbol mean?

Tags: php, operators, porting

I have this code, I'm trying to port from php to c/objective-c:

```
if ($byteIndex < count($data) ) {
    $light = ( ( ($data[$byteIndex] >> $bitIndex) & 1) == 1);
}
```

But I can't seem to find anywhere what the >> is indicating here. nor the "& 1", for that matter.

Comment: Those are [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). I'd explain what they do, except I have no clue. They are to me a black art of inscrutable design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: @sdl You're thinking too high level there. The answer is 101010. :o)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bitwise operators - Shift Right and And :)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

```
$score = 2295;

echo((($score >> 2) & 1) == 1)? "1": "^1"; // 1
echo((($score >> 3) & 1) == 1)? "1": "^1"; // ^1
```

The question is what are you shifting and how many bits? Is it something with colors?

Using `&` and `>>` to convert hexadecimal to RGB (decimal).

```
$hex = 0xCCFF33; // my favourite :)

$r = $hex >> 16;
$g = ($hex & 0x00FF00) >> 8;
$b = $hex & 0x0000FF;

printf("rgb(%d,%d,%d)", $r, $g, $b); // rgb(204,255,51)
```

This is what happens: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fbitshe.htm